# Questions coming over from Stack Overflow

Tags: support

So I just noticed this one.

[Sitecore media ashx not resizing the image (version 7.2)](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1749/sitecore-media-ashx-not-resizing-the-image-version-7-2)

[image]

And while I am of course thrilled to see this, what controls this process might I ask? :-)

Comment: Ooohh.. shiny migration!?! Yeah, I'd be interested in knowing both A) how did this happen and is it ok that it did?

Comment: Was migrated by http://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt - Matt